# Problems getting database from SD card

Tags: android, android-sqlite, android-sdcard

I'm trying to read a SQLite database stored on the SDCard. Part of the code is as follows:

```
public String getTables() {
    String dbFullPath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + "/external_sd/database.db";
    String query = "SELECT name from sqlite_master where type='table'";
    SQLiteDatabase mDatabase = SQLiteDatabase
            .openDatabase(dbFullPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY
                    + SQLiteDatabase.NO_LOCALIZED_COLLATORS);
    Log.d(TAG, "Is db open? " + mDatabase.isOpen());
    Cursor cursor = mDatabase.rawQuery(query, null);
    String tables = cursor.getString(0);
    cursor.close();

    return tables;
}
```

However, when running this code, I get the following error

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{...}: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: unable to open database file: , while compiling: SELECT name from sqlite_master where type='table'

on the `Cursor cursor = mDatabase.rawQuery(query, null);` line.

The debug log returns `Is db open? true`, meaning that I got the path right and that the database was successfully opened?

Comment: Try another statement what will happen and then let me know.

Comment: @Sajmon Same thing, this should be a simple debug query that works with any valid database.

Answer (score 0):

```
Cursor cursor = mDatabase.query(sqlite_master, new String[] { "name" }, "type=" + table, null,
                null, null, "name asc");
```

Comment: Doesn't work :( Still the same problem: `Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: unable to open database file: , while compiling: SELECT name FROM sqlite_master WHERE type='table' ORDER BY name asc`

Comment: check if the field you specified in query i.e. type and name exist or not in sqlite_master?

Comment: Yeah, I opened the database with another app and the query works fine. I think I opened the database wrong somehow, but the debug log implies that I opened it properly.

Comment: Sorry, I mean, both query works with another code. But it doesn't work with this code snippet for some reason. So the problem is not in the query.